# Wildfly missing/unavailable dependencies

Tags: deployment, wildfly

Wildfly 10 on deploy

Can you help me with such error

```
11:25:36,039 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "console-dev.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.global.\"services-1.0.5\".\"api.ejb-1.1\".\"ActionsFacadeBean!by.common.api.IActionsService\""
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.module.console-dev.console-dev.env.\"by.abank.admin.ui.factory.EJBFactory\".iActionsService is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.global.\"services-1.0.5\".\"api.ejb-1.1\".\"ActionsFacadeBean!by.common.api.IActionsService\"]",
    ]
}
```

I have `service.ear` with 
`@Stateless @Remote ActionsFacadeBean`

And `console-dev.war`

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/services-1.0.5/api.ejb-1.1/ActionsFacadeBean!by.common.api.IActionsService")
protected IActionsService iActionsService;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? cross application injection?

Comment: Only deploy. But all work fine